# Sync music and video folders from mac laptop to ubuntu HTPC

Tags: macos, ubuntu, htpc, kodi

I use a macbook pro w/ 10.6 to rip DVDs and manage music and sync to our Evos. I mount the music and video folders on the ubuntu 10.4 HTPC as volumes on the MBP via WiFi and periodically copy new files to the HTPC. FWIW, I use XBMC to play back content.

Is there a better (i.e., less manual) way? I would love for files to migrate to the HTPC automatically, like dropbox (although I have too much music and video to make using dropbox practical).

I am open to all solutions save maintaining all libraries on the HTPC (I like ubuntu, but I think my fiancee would break the engagement if I made her use the ubuntu box to sync phones... although doubletwist on the mac is far from perfect).

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it as a previous [question](https://superuser.com/questions/97497/one-way-syncing-backup-with-unison). I will rsync when I get home, but it should do the trick.

Comment: `rsync -rvu * /target/` works like a charm.