# Prefer the other machine without having to set up a socket?

Tags: linux, unison

I use [Unison](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) to sync stuff between some Linux devices. I want to have a profile set up where, if I'm running unison from machine A to sync between A and B, I can override my prefer = newer setting and preferpartial certain files from B over files from A, even if A's are newer.

Reading the docs, it seems like the only way I can do that is by setting up a socket on B, and either making sure I can refer to B by its hostname, or keep track of its IP address. [This answer to another post](https://superuser.com/a/296663/860979) seems to have confirmed that that is the way.

But that seems super roundabout for something that really shouldn't have been hard to implement as a simple option that doesn't need to refer to the other machine in a 2-machine operation by hostname or IP. Isn't there a simpler way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you write an [`ignore` pattern](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/download/releases/stable/unison-manual.html#pathspec) to match the certain files you are talking about? If so, what you could do is to use separate Unison profiles. First run Unison with a profile that does most of your syncing with all your `prefer` and `preferpartial` options, but ignore the files you're talking about. Then run Unison with a profile that is exactly the same except without the `perfer` or `preferpartial` or `ignore` options. The only changes that Unison will detect during that second run will be the files you wanted to prefer the copy on root A over the copy on root B. So you can just tell Unison to prefer root A in this second profile.